# Angular 5 how to make a chain of Observable operators like function to avoid rewrite code many times?

Tags: angular, service, observable

I followed topic here [HTTP Example with Observables](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-observables/).
And I write my own app follow this topic, but my app have more than one autosearch input, it about 5 or 6 autosearch inputs like this, each input have it's own url address to search, and my problem is I have to write same code 5 or 6 times, here my code

```
this.myForm.get('input1').valueChanges
  .pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  filter(term => term.length > 0),
  switchMap(term => this.searchSevice.filter(term, option1),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  )
  .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);

this.myForm.get('input2').valueChanges
  .pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  filter(term => term.length > 0),
  switchMap(term => this.searchSevice.filter(term, option2),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  )
  .subscribe(result => this.array2Filtered = result);

this.myForm.get('input3').valueChanges
  .pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  filter(term => term.length > 0),
  switchMap(term => this.searchSevice.filter(term, option3),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  )
  .subscribe(result => this.array3Filtered = result); ... and go on many input fields next
```

and my question is how to avoid this case? Anyway to declare a function or angular service use these chain of observable operators and one or some parameters to use anytime I need instead of rewrite same code many times

Thanks

Comment: Just make a wrapper method that takes 3 arguments: input, option and array, then calls the above code with the args dropped in the right places?

Comment: many thanks, I will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function:

```
forInput(input: AbstractControl, option:any) {
   return input.valueChanges
     .pipe(
         debounceTime(100),
         distinctUntilChanged(),
         filter(term => term.length > 0),
         switchMap(term => this.searchSevice.filter(term, option2),
         takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
     );
}
```

Using function:

```
this.forInput(this.myForm.get('input1'), option1)
    .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);
this.forInput(this.myForm.get('input2'), option2)
    .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);
this.forInput(this.myForm.get('input3'), option3)
    .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);
```

Alternatively, if you want to inline a lambda function:

```
let forInput = (input: AbstractControl, option:any) => {
   return input.valueChanges
     .pipe(
         debounceTime(100),
         distinctUntilChanged(),
         filter(term => term.length > 0),
         switchMap(term => this.searchSevice.filter(term, option2),
         takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
     );
}

forInput(this.myForm.get('input1'), option1)
    .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);
forInput(this.myForm.get('input2'), option2)
    .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);
forInput(this.myForm.get('input3'), option3)
    .subscribe(result => this.array1filtered = result);
```

Comment: Hi, I have to delare a type of input as AbstractControl instead of FormControl

Comment: Is which better way if I subcribe inside ngOnInit and unsubcribe on ngOnDestroy or subcribe on input event onfocus and unsubcribe on onblur event?

Comment: I would unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own operator for this case:

```
const ownOperator = (option) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
    debounceTime(100),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(term => term.length > 0),
    switchMap(term => this.searchSevice.filter(term, option),
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
)
```

And use it:

```
this.myForm.get('input3').valueChanges
  .pipe(ownOperator(option3))
  .subscribe(result => this.array3Filtered = result);
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md